# Having interfaces extend to base abstract class

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface, abstract-class

I'm trying to have a base service that has common functionality that is inherited by all other services, but am having trouble and getting the following error:

```
Type 'BaseService<Test>' in interface list is not an interface
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this? Or a better way to go about this?

Base Service

```
public class BaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly Context _db;
        public BaseService()
        {

        }
        public BaseService(Context db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public async Task<bool> Insert(T entity)
        {
            entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            await _db.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            try
            {
                return await _db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0 ? true : false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then a normal service that would have access to this but where the error is displaying

```
public interface ITestService : BaseService<Test>
    {
    }
```

Comment: Interfaces can't inherit from classes, only from other interfaces.  Typically you would introduce an interface that `BaseService<T>` implements.  And don't swallow the Exceptions, or use a boolean return value to indicate success or failure.  Just `throw` or don't `catch` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface cannot inherit from a class. Here `BaseService<T>` is defined as a class.

A way to fix it is to declare the service as a class, as follow:

```
public class TestService : BaseService<Test>
{
}
```